# Using QML FileDialog leads to "Binding loop" in ToolBar

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qt5

I have an issue that I can't solve by myself. I develop a UI using this third party library/framework - https://github.com/papyros/qml-material. It is with controls and layouts developed according to the Google Guidelines. The problem is that when I use FileDialog in the project, the page that it is defined in loads slowly and I get the following messages:

```
file:///C:/.../QtQuick/Controls/ToolBar.qml:146:9: QML QQuickItem*: Binding loop detected for property "layoutHeight"
file:///C:/.../QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:407:9: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///C:/.../QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml:407:9: QML ToolBar: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
```

It will be great if someone knows the answer.

**The issue can be reproduced very easily with the Demo that is in the GitHub project of the library - https://github.com/papyros/qml-material/tree/develop/demo. Just add FileDialog somewhere there and see how the page will be loaded and what messages you will get.**

Qt version used: 5.12.6

Comment: Do you have a "minimal" example (see [mre]) to demonstrate the problem? I'd rather not download an entire huge project.

Comment: I just was about to recommend to raise an issue in that GitHub project but I noticed you already did: [FileDialog doesn't work properly. #496](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material/issues/496) 

Comment: @JarMan it will be great, but the thing is that it can't be and successful example without the whole project. Without the project it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat known problem with `FileDialog`s when put in `Loader`s that are set to `asynchronous` loading. Here is a complete example demonstrating the problem:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Loader {
        sourceComponent: FileDialog {}
        asynchronous: true // change to false and ToolBar binding loop goes away
    }
}
```

I noticed that the project you have referenced uses an asynchronous Loader in main.qml, so it appears that this is causing your issue. See line 243:

```
                Loader {
                    id: example
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    asynchronous: true
```

I have found [one bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55924?attachmentOrder=desc) but it has been closed as unresolved. My understanding of this problem is that the error only affects the "backup" `QFileDialog` that only appears if an OS-specific one is not available. From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html):

> The implementation of FileDialog will be a platform file dialog if possible. If that isn't possible, then it will try to instantiate a QFileDialog.

In my experience, on Windows and Mac, the binding loop error causes no problems and can be ignored because the OS file dialog always appears. I also don't think it is a correctable error outside of not using the `asynchronous` flag, as it is a Qt bug.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you that you investigated the whole project just to help me with my problem. It seems that was the problem. As soon as I moved these dialogs out of the loader it works fine and smooth!